# Is it possible for a spring bean to get notified about application context initialization errors?

Tags: java, spring

I have a singleton bean in my spring context (call it 'beanX' ) that, when started spins off a few other threads and creates some state on the file system. 
So I want to stop it in a clean way so that resources are freed when the context is shut down.

I have annotated it with `@Bean(destroyMethod = "shutdown")` and that works as expected without any problems.

Further information is that this bean loads very early in the context startup sequence (as it has many other beans that use it directly and indirectly) and there are many other beans that loads after it.

Now to the problem: it is fairly common that when we do development one of the other beans fail to start and makes the startup of the spring context to fail - but in these cases the beanX is not shut down properly.

This is perhaps ok in 'productionCode' as that usually means that the whole jvm stops and then resources are cleaned up - BUT when we run our 1000+ unit test suite (and some of the tests has an error causing the context to crash) this becomes a real problem because the test JVM is not stopped between tests, and a new spring context is created after each failing test - even though the test that failed has not properly cleaned up after itself as beanX is started but never stopped!

Today my laptop created 5 million file handles and 13k threads when I ran the test suite because of this.

SO, the only way we could make this work currently is to make beanX be a public static field (ClassX.beanX) that is lazily initialized by the spring context - and then in our test code manually call the ClassX.beanX.shutdown() if any context loading error occurs.

But I am curios if there is a better/different 'Spring' way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **event handling** in [Spring](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-events).

> Event handling in the ApplicationContext is provided through the
>   ApplicationEvent class and ApplicationListener interface. **If a bean**
>   that implements the **ApplicationListener** interface is deployed into the
>   context, **every time** an ApplicationEvent gets published to the
>   ApplicationContext, **that bean is notified**. Essentially, this is the
>   standard **Observer design pattern**.

Comment: Thx, we have done some 'toy' tests with this approach and it seems to solve the problem. The ContextClosedEvent is fired to all listeners before the spring context throws the error out to the thread calling refresh().

This is also documented [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ConfigurableApplicationContext.html#refresh--)